# Change default editor in LXD snap

Tags: lxc, lxd

I recently migrated from LXD installed from deb, to LXD installed from snap. The default editor is set to Vim. How can I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LXD snap package checks whether you have set the EDITOR environment variable. If you have set it, it will use that text-mode text editor, otherwise it will select a default for you.

Therefore, set the variable EDITOR to `nano` as follows. Then, in the example (profile edit) it will open it up with `nano`.

```
$ export EDITOR=nano
$ lxc profile edit default
```

To make the change permanent, run the following once:

```
echo 'export EDITOR=nano' >> ~/.profile 
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: You are my hero.

Comment: Strangely while this works when specifying `nano`, it does not work for me with `emacs` or even `emacs24-nox`. Anyone know why that is and what I can do about it (other than to use nano of course, emacs happens to be my preferred editor :-)

Comment: I think I got the cause of this issue: The editor is run inside the lxd snap so it has to be available there to work. At least that is the reasoning I got from reading [an lxd bug](https://github.com/lxc/lxd-pkg-snap/issues/9). Emacs (even without X support) would probably be considered too big to include in the snap. The question remains though, how can I use emacs to edit files in my lxd containers?

Comment: Nope. That won't work. `lxc` ignores your `~/.profile` altogether.

Comment: @foki actually it does. I was confronted with nano and was able to switch to vim this way.